# Bottle opener - what is the use for the other part?

Tags: preparation-for-drinking

The blue socket is used to open beer bottles.

But what is the usage for the red one?
[image]

Comment: I've always used it to get things out from between my teeth.  But then again, I'm British.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this amazon page : [https://www.amazon.com/Colorful-Mcyye-Keychain-Beverage-Practical/dp/B08RY4FFT5/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08RY4FFT5)

This is to help open beer cans by sliding it under the pull tab:

[image: Pepsi can being opened with the opener]